# Как сделать адаптивность на Joomla

Tags: html, css, joomla, cms

Добрый день, Привет всем ребята!

Мне необходимо сделать адаптивный дезайн для сайта на движке `Joomla`, мне сказали чтобы изменений в HTML коде не было, я понимаю что лучше сделать свойствам `display:flex`, но к сожалению здесь такое требование.

Вот HTML код:

```
<div class="custom">
    <table class="yslygi">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="/images/pencil.png" alt="" /></td>
                <td><img src="/images/arrow.png" alt="" /></td>
                <td><img src="/images/larry.png" alt="" /></td>
                <td><img src="/images/arrow.png" alt="" /></td>
                <td><img src="/images/tools.png" alt="" /></td>
                <td><img src="/images/arrow.png" alt="" /></td>
                <td><img src="/images/clock.png" alt="" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Вот CSS код:

```
.yslygi {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
}
.yslygi tr:first-child td:nth-child(2n+1) {
    width: 150px;
    padding: 20px 0 11px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В принципе, **адаптивность никак не привязана к CMS**, на который фронту нужна адаптация. Добавляйте `@media` правила в стили и с большой вероятностью, всё можно будет адаптировать без правок html кода (кроме раскрытия-сворачивания меню, к примеру, где требуется дополнительный элемент триггера).